# Почему не работает drag and drop?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает `drag and drop` в `sublime`? подключил `jquery` и проверил точно ли я его установил. Может кто то сталкивался с таким?

вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#draggable').draggable();

        });
    </script>




    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-error">
        Перетащи меня
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: проверили. и что дала проверка? ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: нет, jquery подключен, в webstorm этот код работал а в sublimt нет...

Comment: в смысле "в вебшторм работал а в сублиме нет"?) код работает в браузере, а не в редакторе кода. вы же его в браузере открываете, надеюсь?

Comment: естественно, я не пойму в чем проблема код скинул в вопросе...проверьте может у вас работает если вам не трудно

Comment: не работает. почему - добавил в ответе. просто я не понял, что вы имели ввиду утверждая, что "в вебшторм работало".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли подключить библиотеку jQuery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Функция `$.draggable()` не является частью скрипта jQuery, но входит в библиотеку jQuery UI.

Comment: спасиииииииииииииииииииииииииибооооооооооооо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!